# Google Oauth 2.0 - consent screen suppress developer email address

Tags: google-oauth

We have developed Google Sign In on our website using Google Oauth 2.0 . So in the consent screen that comes up in this login process, there is a developer info pop up that appears when somebody clicks on the down arrow next to the product name.

Is there a way not to show that email address in that developer info or just not show developer info at all ?

Answer (score 11):

I don't believe so - the intention is to give the user who is being asked to authorize your application confidence that the application is developed by a reputable source - in this case an email address verified as belonging to the developer.

I believe it is possible to change this address by adding another email address to the project team as an "Owner", logging in as that user, then editing the consent screen.

Comment: This is correct. Invite another user and you can change the primary email.

Comment: I missed the part where you said "logging in as that user" and got stuck for a bit. This is important. As of right now the e-mail is not automatically appearing in the list when a new owner is added.

Comment: But when you login to youtube using google sign in, the product **YouTube** is not clickable and hence, you dont see the developer info at all